# Pull RSS Feed Title with Google Feeds API

Tags: javascript, json, rss

I'm using the Google Feeds API to build a custom RSS feed viewer, but I've run into a bit of a snag, and Google's documentation isn't a ton of help. :(

I have everything working pulling content from the actual feed, like so...

```
var feed = new google.feeds.Feed("http://feeds.mashable.com/Mashable");
      feed.setNumEntries(5);
      feed.load(function(result) {
        if (!result.error) {
          var container = document.getElementById("mashableSide");
          for (var i = 0; i < result.feed.entries.length; i++) {
            var entry = result.feed.entries[i];
            var li = document.createElement("li");
            li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(entry.title));
            container.appendChild(li);
          }
        }
      });
```

But I need to pull the **title and description from the feed itself**. No matter what I try all it displays is "undefined".

Here's what I've tried...

```
var feed = new google.feeds.Feed("http://feeds.mashable.com/Mashable");
      feed.load(function(result) {
        if (!result.error) {
          var container = document.getElementById("mashableSide");
          for (var i = 0; i < result.feed.entries.length; i++) {
            var entry = result.feed.entries[i];
            var li = document.createElement("li");
            li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(feed.title));
            container.appendChild(li);
          }
        }
      });
```

Any ideas?

Note: I know the Google Feed API is depreciated, but I want to use it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Call the `result` object's fields:

```
li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(result.feed.title));
li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(result.feed.description));
```